# Missing mysql on /etc/init.d/ directory

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, mysql-workbench, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been trying to install mysql using WSL and I've followed the steps indicated in this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database. I tried running `mysql --version` and it worked (prompted `mysql  Ver 8.0.23 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`). But as I try the next command `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`, it says `sudo: /etc/init.d/mysql: command not found`. I've also tried checking the contents of `/etc/init.d/` directory and there is no existing mysql file/folder there. What should I do next to proceed with my mysql installation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There is a great blog post on this problem, with explanations of the issue and detailed solutions.
https://www.58bits.com/blog/2020/05/03/installing-mysql-80-under-wsl-2-and-ubuntu

From the post:

> One solution is to download the mysql.server.sh script from here -
> https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/tree/8.0/support-files - and
> then copy and rename the script to /etc/init.d/mysql (make sure that
> it's also executable - chmod +x mysql)
>
> You'll then need to set the default values for basdir, datadir and pid
> file locations.
>
> Here's an excerpt with the top portion of the file and the settings
> that worked for me...
>
> ```
> # If you change base dir, you must also change datadir. These may get
> # overwritten by settings in the MySQL configuration files.
>
> basedir=/usr
> datadir=/var/lib/mysql
>
> # Default value, in seconds, afterwhich the script should timeout waiting
> # for server start.
> # Value here is overriden by value in my.cnf.
> # 0 means don't wait at all
> # Negative numbers mean to wait indefinitely
> service_startup_timeout=900
>
> # Lock directory for RedHat / SuSE.
> lockdir='/var/lock/subsys'
> lock_file_path="$lockdir/mysql"
>
> # The following variables are only set for letting mysql.server find things.
>
> # Set some defaults
> mysqld_pid_file_path=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
> if test -z "$basedir"
> ```
>
> After this you should be able to start and stop MySQL as follows:
>
> ```
> sudo service mysql start
> sudo service mysql stop
> ```

As he mentions later, you also need to create /var/run/mysqld/ and set permissions:

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```